# I want to pass the value of grid-template-areas in props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am using react and styled-components.
I want to change the style of  grid-template-areas according to the value passed in props.
I am using styled-components, but the grid-template-areas style is not applied properly.
When I look at it in the developer tools, it looks like the image, which means the style is not applied.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

type Props = {
  page: 'home' | 'user' | 'group';
};

export const Container: React.FC<Props> = ({page, children}) => {
  const dataList = {
    home: {
      gridTemplateAreas: 'header body',
      gridTemplateRows: '60px calc(100vh - 50px)',
    },
   user: {
      gridTemplateAreas: 'header header', 'body body',
      gridTemplateRows: '60px calc(100vh - 100px)',
    },
    group: {
      gridTemplateAreas: 'header body',
      gridTemplateRows: '60px calc(100vh - 30px)',
    },
  };
  const data = dataList[page];
  return <Box {...data}>{children}</Box>;
};

type StyledProps = {
  gridTemplateAreas: any;
  gridTemplateRows: string;
  padding: number;
};

const Box = styled.div<StyledProps>`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: ${(props) => props.gridTemplateAreas};
  grid-template-rows: ${(props) => props.gridTemplateRows};
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grid-template-areas`' value should be enclosed in quotes, try this:

```
  const dataList = {
    home: {
      gridTemplateAreas: `"header body"`,
      gridTemplateRows: '60px calc(100vh - 50px)',
    },
   user: {
      gridTemplateAreas: `"header header" "body body"`,
      gridTemplateRows: '60px calc(100vh - 100px)',
    },
    group: {
      gridTemplateAreas: `"header body"`,
      gridTemplateRows: '60px calc(100vh - 30px)',
    },
  };
```